# How to auto update data in vuejs model from global object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

This is my first project with vuejs and i have problem with auto update data from global object.
In my project i'm using es6 and vuejs.

I need to disabled/enabled button and when i changing disabled option in global object to false button is't enable.

Here is simple fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/daer/nsk95tez/

When i click "Change state" state.disabled is changing to false but Button is't enable :(

```
<div id="some">
  <p>Current state: {{disabled}}</p>
  <button type="button" v-bind:disabled="disabled">Button</button>
</div>
<br>
<button id="state" type="button" v-on:click="changeState">Change state</button>

class stateList {
    constructor() {
        this.disabled = true;
    }
};
// export default (new stateList);


// import state from '../state/';
var state = new stateList;

var some = new Vue({
  el: '#some',
  data: {
    disabled: state.disabled
  },
  methods: {
    methodOne: function(e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});

var changeState = new Vue({
  el: '#state',
  methods: {
    changeState: function(e) {
      state.disabled = false;
      alert(state.disabled);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you your not actually changing the variable `data.disabled` so the button state isn't changing. You are creating a data object and a state object and copying one value `data.disabled=state.disabled` between them at creation of the Vue instance (your not actually passing a reference to the variable just the variable itself). You need to set the state object as the data object.

```
el: '#some',
data: state,
methods: {
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nsk95tez/2/

However you really don't need a es6 class to store state. One of the key parts about Vue.js is that the data variable is a simple object. Es6 class is syntactic sugar for creating objects with inheritance which you don't need in this scenario.

Try this

```
var state = {disable:true};
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nsk95tez/1/ Here is the modified js fiddle example.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer very helped me.